# Sending data from Azure App Service to external process

Tags: c++, azure, sockets, websocket, network-programming

A C++ module present in Azure web app service needs to send a stream of profiling data as a char buffer regularly to an JAVA process that is running in some other external machine.(External machine may be some physical / VM globally)

To achieve this, the first thing that comes to mind is an dedicated TCP socket. The process acts as a server and the sending module will act as client.

But i am not sure about the efficiency and security of the connection. Is there any other secured and efficient approach for this scenario..? It should be a two way communicable dedicated connection.

Comment: What is the data that needs to flow.
What does the data hold.
Where is the external machine.
Voting for close unless these details are provied.

Comment: @bashrc details added